# Get variable information from elf file

Tags: c#, parsing, elf

I'm trying to make a simple watch screen GUI on C#. I have an elf file, I need to get below information for every variable in this elf file.

- Variable Name
- Variable Size
- Variable Address

I can do this by `readelf` executable installed for windows. I'm not really experienced on using this kind of tools with C#. But I was able to run it in cmd screen in windows and get a correct result like below:

-> `readelf -s test.elf | grep sineWave1_100MS`

<- `373: 200006e0     2 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 sineWave1_100MS`

I am okay with using this kind of executables but I want my application to run on every pc. Can we just use copy this exe file (readelf) to my applications directory and call the command from my c# application? I tried that but I get some dll error if I try to run this command from a different directory.

I don't want anyone to install `binutils` or `cygwin` setups to run my application. How can I simply get variable information from an elf file using a C# application?

Comment: There are many ELF parsers on the internet. Sorry, I am not in a position to recommend any of them, which would be off-topic here anyway.